# Mysql-workbench import data from csv fails

Tags: mysql, csv

I want to add fields to into a created table called 'Deporte', i follow the process and when i arrive to finally workbench shows to me

> table Deporte has been used, 0 records imported

My table over i want to load data have more fields than my csv file, but in the process of import i can select the fields couples i want to load.
However, if i create a new table with my data, the import process is completed correctly. I have this captures of the procedure that i want:
[image]
[image]

[image]

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that my URL fields was not long enough.